# c# wpf app convert to dll - xaml errors

Tags: c#, wpf, dll

I'm trying to "convert" my wpf wpplication to an unique `DLL` to use it from another `DLL`.

the problem is that, if I do that :

```
1.open the project in visual studio 
2.Right click on project. 
3.Go to properties. 
4.Select output type to "Class Library"
```

I have a large number of errors due to the xaml...

Any ideas how to convert it to a dll without thoses problems?

thanks

Comment: Does your WPF project have main method for execution? DLL dont have main method. Check if this is problem.

Comment: Also please list all errors, you are getting.It will help us to identify problem.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert your WPF application to a DLL to be able to reference it from a DLL.

A .exe application is a standard assembly, you can directly reference it from another project if you want.

It should solve your compilation problem.

Regards,

Comment: I don't want to use it as a .exe. This program use other DLL, and I want to to be a DLL too. the goal is to call couples of fonctions of the program, into an another DLL

Comment: Why not externalizing your functions into a new Class Library project referenced by both projects ?

Comment: because the program use views (in xaml) and I really need thoses views

Comment: You can copy paste your view files in any class library that references WindowsBase, PresentationCore, PresentationFramework